# How to disable an input when its sibling is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<table>
 <tr class="name"><td><input type="hidden" value="name1" name="name"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
 <tr class="name"><td><input type="hidden" value="name2" name="name"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
</table>
```

i was try:

```
$('.name').find("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
        var check = $(this).attr('checked');
        $(this).find(input[type='hidden']).attr('disable',!check )
      })
```

i want when `checkbox` is checked, input `type="hidden` will be disable, but it working wrong with my code !

Comment: just a note: you shouldn't be using tables to structure your HTML. Use divs, sections etc. with css. Table-based html is very 90s and should be only used for HTML emails

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: 1st. use form and labels 2nd. show your code

Comment: I use the table for other purposes @treyBake

Comment: @themanhNguyen such as?

Comment: @treyBake '90 or '00 is irrelevant. To semantically represent tabular data, `<table>` still rules. I though agree that *input* and *checkbox* are no *'data'*, but perhaps we're missing the bigger picture.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan true - but as we can only see inputs - it's safe to assume that it's semantically incorrect by todays standards. Agreed, we may need more code to speak in absolutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a handler for 'change' event, look up for closest parent row and switch disabled property on/off depending on whether checkbox is checked.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $row = $this.closest('tr');
    $row.find('input[type="hidden"]').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

<strike>Side note: Question does not contain any code that shows what you tried and as you can see answer is pretty simple.</strike>

<strike>Haven't tested it tho, you might need to switch `.prop` with `.attr`.</strike>
JSFiddle with code courtesy of Nathan Champion [jsfiddle.net/3qg6Ljev](http://jsfiddle.net/3qg6Ljev)

If you need more inputs in rows, then you will need to add a class to hidden input that should work in pair with checkbox and use `.find('input.class')` instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, see, that only shows how little I work with JS. Yes, `this.checked` is obviously prefered.

Comment: $this will be the same as php variable?

Comment: @themanhNguyen not exactly. Strictly speaking, it's a convention that I picked up from jQuery docs to prepend every variable representing a jQuery object with `$` sign. Creating those two variables ($this and $row) can be ommited, but it helps with readability for little to no performance loss.

Comment: can i change it with another name?!

Comment: @themanhNguyen yes, obviously, as long as you're consistent and change their occurences as well. Remember that any string starting with `_`, `$` or any letter is valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

So your HTML is like;

```
<table>
   <tr class="name">
      <td><input type="hidden" value="name1" name="name"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="name">
      <td><input type="hidden" value="name2" name="name"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now in JS:

```
$(document).on('change', "[type='checkbox']", function() {
     var isDisabled = $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('input').prop('disabled');
     $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('input').prop('disabled', !isDisabled);
});
```

Comment: I understand what it's trying to achieve (show / hide input) it doesn't do what was asked (disabling hidden input) and does not switch back after unchecking the checkbox. I'd say a plus for event delegation, but for a newbie it might be confusing.

Comment: "disabling hidden input" -> What exactly does it mean? If input type="hidden" then what is the purpose of disabling it?

Comment: to prevent sending whatever name/value data combination is contained in that hidden input. Disabled inputs are excluded from form data when submitted.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Changed the answer please check, if it works.

Comment: `var isDisabled = $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('input').prop('disabled');` is not ok due to two things: it checks the wrong property (`disabled` instead of `checked`) and I'd say it should check the value of checkbox in question (`this`), not all inputs in sibling cells (checkbox included). Then `$(this).closest('td').siblings().find('input')` will find checkbox element as well and possibly disable it as well, which is probably not what would be wanted. You might want to look at my answer too :)